# Run magento update script one time for creating an attribute

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a problem using the thumbnail upload in the admin catalog category view in the Magento backend. Since i updated to 1.9.3.1 i can not upload image anymore. The upload button appears but the transfered data is still not showing in the backend.

I found out, that the Module xml_connect is responsible for creating the thumbnail attribute (its a mistery to me why this module is responsible for that), otherwise the transfered thumbnail data obviously will be discarded.

In the install-1.6.0.0.php of the module i find (among others) the following content

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'thumbnail', array(
   'type' => 'varchar',
   'label' => 'Thumbnail Image',
   'input' => 'image',
   'backend' => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
   'required' => false,
   'sort_order' => 4,
   'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
   'group'=> 'General Information'
));
```

If this was ran, the image upload works.

In my case its a bit special. In earlier Magento versions, it seems that the xml_connect module was already enabled, cause there are xml_connect tables in my database. In the current version the xml_connect isn't enabled, so i tried to delete the module entry for xml_connect to rerun the install script. But that fails on sql update script, cause the tables already exists ... if i delete all xml_connect tables, it works fine and the thumbnails can be uploaded.

So actually i got a solution by reactivating the module and deleting the tables before. But in reality its not practical to me to do that on a productive system ...

I found another page showing a solution by juggling with several SQL-Queries with collecting attribute id's by hand ... i think thats also very vulnerable to errors ...

So my question. Is there a way to run the installer->addAttribute code above 'once' without the context of a concrete module? Is there another nice way to get the thumbnail attribute in the database?

Thanks

Comment: Normally categories have no thumbnails in Magento, when xml_connect module was introduced, one was needed and added (with that module, instead of a feature of its own). For a solution to your problem, it is normally enough to reset the module / db versions (that is meta-data in a db table of it's own, Magerun supports these operations) and run the upgrade again. Alternatively you can create yourself a thumbnail module (if there isn't any available yet, I would assume if xml_connect is finally disabled, others are having this issue, too).